# Page action to open new page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I use a page action to directly open a new page?  I have a link in my popup.html, but it would be better to have the page open when they click the icon so that they would only need one click instead of two.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Popup</title>
    <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="http://www.domain.com/details.html" target="_blank">click here</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a way to achieve this would be as follows:

```js
 chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){

     chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.domain.com/details.html", "active":true});

 });
```

See [Chrome Page Action | onClicked](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction.html#events)

Note that you will need to declare the tabs permission in your manifest file:

```
"permissions": ["tabs",...],
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `tabs` permission. `tabs` is a powerful permission, so I suggest you don't declare it light-heartedly !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any elegant way to handle both the situations on page action click:

1. Open popup
2. Open a new page

If you always want to open a new tab with some URL whenever page action is clicked, just remove the popup. And use the code just like @Flo has mentioned.

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.example.com", "active":true});
});
```

PS: To remove the popup, there are two options:

1. Remove the popup from manifest.json
2. Pragmatically like `chrome.pageAction.setPopup('')`